# How do you estimate the performance of a classifier on test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit to make a supervised classifier and I am currently tuning it to give me good accuracy on the labeled data. But how do I estimate how well it does on the test data (unlabeled)?

Also, how do I find out if I'm starting to overfit the classifier?

Comment: Use the classifier's `score` method, or one of the performance metrics in `sklearn.metrics`. See also the tutorials and the examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can't score your method on unlabeled data because you need to know right answers. In order to evaluate a method you should split your trainset into (new) train and test (via [sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html), for example). Then fit the model to the train and score it on test.
If you don't have a lot of data and holding out some of it may negatively impact performance of an algorithm, use [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html).

Since overfitting is inability to generalize, low test scores is a good indicator of it.

For more theory and some other approaches, take a look at [this article](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/MeasuringError.html).

Comment: I'm testing the classifier with `cross_val_score` and the parameter `scoring='f1'` but it says that some of the sum of true positives and false positives are equal to zero. Is this because some of my classes are really small in size compared to the others? Shouldn't the stratified option be enabled by default to prevent this?