# evaluation metrics for compare between classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to classify a small dataset (around 10000 records) into two classes. I used various methods like DT, Naive Bayes and k-nn classifier. Now, I would like to set the results from one of the classifiers are my baseline and perform a statistical hypothesis testing. I am not much familiar with this field of statistical testing, and I wonder how to proceed on this.

I have been thinking of setting the DT classifier as my baseline, but I am not sure how to perform a t-test (or similar) on the data. The input dataset has 192 attributes. Should I use the classification results from two classifiers and do a paired t-test on them? For example, I could take the result from Naive Bayes and perform the paired t-test with the DT results (which is the baseline). Is this the right approach?

Also, I am confused with the explanation for null and alternate hypothesis. Could someone be willing to give an idea about how to fix the null and alternate hypothesis.

Comment: Hard to understand what are you asking. If what you want is to evaluate your DT model, try some of the binary metrics given by sklearn. Read the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics), classification report and confusion matrix are important

Comment: i ask about how to compare performance of two algorithms

Comment: Then yes, it's what I am linking you. Since you are doing a supervised approach, you should start using accuracy/precision/recall/f-score metrics. In order to avaluate them, first you should split your dataset into a train and test set, train the algorithm with the train set and then predict the test set. With the prediction of the test set, you should compare the prediction with the reality using the basic metrics that I told you. Furthermore, it's important to read the documentation that I linked, since the important part is to know how the metrics work :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you estimate the performance of a classifier on test data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315765/how-do-you-estimate-the-performance-of-a-classifier-on-test-data)

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and, in my opinion, off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see: [help/on-topic], [ask].